# Filtering elements from a List of a created Data Type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell & i was trying to filter elements from a created Data Type called Hoover.

Now a Hoover has a Price & a Wattage 
, I defined Hoover as :

```
data Hoover = HH Price Wattage
```

&
Price & Wattage as :

```
data Price = P Int 
data Wattage = W Int
```

When i try to run this code for filtering the hoovers from a catalog of differently priced Hoovers :

(Here m is the minimum price and n is the maximum price) :

```
filterProduct :: Price -> Price -> [Hoover] -> [Hoover]
filterProduct (P m) (P n) [] = []
filterProduct (P m) (P n) (x:xs) = if(price >= m && price <= n) then ([x] ++ (filterProduct (P m) (P n) xs))
                                    else (filterProduct (P m) (P n) xs)

where
 x :: Hoover 
 x = HH (P price) watt
```

I get quite a lot of errors, i tried to do a lot of things but couldn't get around it & needed help fixing it

Would appreciate any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program, `price` seems to appear out of "thin air". You do not define it in the head of the expression (before the `=`). So the compiler does not understand what you are doing.

You actually wrote the `where` caluse in the wrong way. The pattern is placed at the *left* side of the equation, so:

```
filterProduct :: Price -> Price -> [Hoover] -> [Hoover]
filterProduct (P m) (P n) [] = []
filterProduct (P m) (P n) (x:xs) = if(price >= m && price <= n) then ([x] ++ (filterProduct (P m) (P n) xs))
                                    else (filterProduct (P m) (P n) xs)

    where HH (P price) watt = x
```

That being said, you make things too hard. You can make use of the [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function here to filter your list:

```
filterProduct :: Price -> Price -> [Hoover] -> [Hoover]
filterProduct (P m) (P n) = filter (\(HH (P price) watt) -> price >= m && price <= n)
```

It furthermore might make more sense to define a type *synonym* with:

```
type Price = Int
type Wattage = Int
```

if you do not plan to define special type class instances on these types.

Comment: Thanks for this ! I'm actually trying to learn haskell so i didn't want to use the filter function and it was the where clause that was at fault.

Comment: You can also derive `Eq` and `Ord` instance for the dedicated types, removing the need to unpack them in order to make the comparisons.

Comment: so, if i did deriving(eq,ord) after my type declaration for Price, could i then just do price1 == price2 or price1 > price2 ? where price1 &price2 are the type Price ?

Answer (score 1):

[Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58356440/5499914) is splendid as always, and it seems to have resolved your issue. I'd still like to put forth another approach, using [record syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes):

```
data Hoover = HH
    { hooverPrice   :: Int
    , hooverWattage :: Int
    }
```

If you declare your type like this, it'll give you two functions `hooverPrice` and `hooverWattage` of type `Hoover -> Int`.

Now, if you have a function that can check whether an `Int` is within your desired price range, you need only compose that function with `hooverPrice`, and you'll have a function that checks whether a vacuum cleaner's price falls within that range. Armed with this function, the problem is reduced to a simple `filter`.